# Typescript 1.8 Angular2 rc1 and injecting a JavaScript library (auth0.js); Cannot find module 'auth0'

Tags: typescript, angular, auth0

I'm trying to use the auth0.js library in my Angular2 rc1 TypeScript project to do a custom signup. I need to inject the auth0 lib into my components and getting a "Cannot find module 'auth0'" from TypeScript.

**configure**

```
npm install auth0-js --save
typings install dt~auth0 --save --global
```

**signupForm.component.ts:**

```
import * as auth0 from "auth0-js"; //TypeScript: TS2307: Cannot find module 'auth0-js'

@Component({...})
export class SignupForm {
  constructor(private auth:auth0){}
  ...
}
```

**main.ts**

```
...
import * as auth0 from "auth0-js"; //TypeScript: TS2307: Cannot find module 'auth0-js'

bootstrap(..., [provide(auth0, { useFactory: () => {
    return new auth0({...});
  }})
]);
```

Comment: Potentially related: https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js/issues/136

Comment: Had a similiar issue, updating the typings helped -> npm install --save @types/auth0-js

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you already installed auth0 types package:
`npm install -D @types/auth0-js`